# How can I generate a different object based on drop-down list parameter and create a dedicated web page?

Tags: angular, reactjs

I'm a novice to Angular technology and web development (I'm more specialized on back-end stuff) and I'd like to build a TicTacToe (starting for a known tutorial found on the internet) web app just to get familiar with this new world. 
I want games to be configurable: players need to choose a 3x3, 5x5 or 10x10 grid, which would then be generated.

Here is the code for my "board.component.ts":

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-board',
  templateUrl: './board.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./board.component.scss']
})
export class BoardComponent implements OnInit {
  squares: string[];
  xIsNext: boolean;
  winner: string;
  gridid:string; 

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { 

    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => this.gridid = params.gridid)
    //this.newGame();
  }

  newGame(x: number) {
    this.squares = Array(x).fill(null);
    this.winner = null;
    this.xIsNext = true;
  }  

  get player() {
    return this.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
  }

  makeMove(idx: number) {
    if (!this.squares[idx]) {
      this.squares.splice(idx, 1, this.player);
      this.xIsNext = !this.xIsNext;
    }

    this.winner = this.calculateWinner();
  }

  calculateWinner() {
    const lines = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6]
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
      if (
        this.squares[a] &&
        this.squares[a] === this.squares[b] &&
        this.squares[a] === this.squares[c]
      ) {
        return this.squares[a];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is my "Gamesetup.component.ts":

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BoardComponent } from '../board/board.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gamesetup',
  templateUrl: './gamesetup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gamesetup.component.scss']
})
export class GamesetupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, 
    private BoardComponent: BoardComponent) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  options = [
    { name: "option1", value: 3 },
    { name: "option2", value: 5 },
    { name: "option3", value: 10 }
  ]

  generateGrid(e) {
    if(e==3) {
      this.BoardComponent.newGame(e); 
    } else {
      if (e == 5) {
        this.BoardComponent.newGame(e);
      } else {
        if (e == 10) {
          this.BoardComponent.newGame(e);
        }
      }
    }  


  }

}
```

This my code for the html part:

```
    <h1>Choose your grid: </h1>
    <form (submit)="generateGrid(o.value)">
        <select required class="form-control" ng-model="selectedId" ng-options="Grid size">
            <option value="">Select Grid Size</option>
            <option *ngFor="let o of options">
                {{o.value}}
            </option>

        </select>
        <nav>
            <button (click)="generateGrid(selectedId)" nbButton outline status="danger">Start new Game</button>
        </nav>

    </form>
</div>


<main>

</main>
```

At the moment, I am not able to correctly visualize the grid (where I could play before adding this configuration logic): can you please help me on the best practices to achieve wanted outcome?

What I want is to:

- Choose grid size
- Click on "Start new Game"
- Be redirected to the desired grid (i think a good idea could be to take the "size" value from the drop-down list and build a grid based on that parameter)
- Play

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

First, use Angular 8 -or Angular 2- ng-select is for AngularJs.

Second use [(ngModel)] in your select and draw so many cell as indicate the select. For template driven form, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms)

For create the cells you use *ngFor, see [the docs again](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngFor)

If you declare a variable "cells" in your .ts

```
cells:number=3;
```

Your select can be like

```
<select [(ngModel)]="cells">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.value">
        {{option.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

*ngFor can only iterate over arrays so, if we has a few elements we can create the array "on-fly" and use slice

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].slice(0,(+cells))">
      {{items}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I'll try it out later! Do you have any tips on how to redirect to different grids?

Comment: No, the idea is has a unique "grid". You can do using two *ngFor, but you only has one component and one grid. See the code I write in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8rh5v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. When you change the select, you change the "list". BTW -there're some errors in the code, I just corrected it

Comment: Thank you in advance! I'll let you know in a few hours when I get back home :)